# Form value with json data in ng-model format

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm having a form element in my html.

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="searchIncident()">
    <select  class="form-control"
            id="category"
            (change)="getSubCategories($event.target.value)"
            (ngModel)="categoryMast.catCode"
            formControlName="catCode">
            <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categoryMaster" value="{{category.catCode}}">{{category.catDesc}}</option>
    </select> 
 </form>
```

Below is my type script.

```
export class ISearchComponent {
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private masterDataService:MasterDataService,private http: Http) { // MasterDataService is defined already
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        'catCode'   : new FormControl(),

     });

}    

//THis is the search Incident method which makes the server call
searchIncident(){
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    this.http.post(AppUtils.INCIDENT_SEARCH, this.myForm.value, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res=>{
             this.rowData = res.json().result;
         }, err=>{             
         });

    }
}
```

Here the submitting json is(this.myForm.value)

```
{
"cateCode":12
}
```

But I need it in the way it defined in the ng-model

```
 "categoryMast": {
    "catCode": 12
  }
```

**Tried Solution:**

One solution is to I need to reform the json so that I can add the categoryMast array, but this will become cumbersome as there will be more field like this.

Comment: then you have to create custom json from posted from data before http post call.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in Tried solution.

Comment: You are passing `this.myForm.value` , Have you tried `this.categoryMast` ?

Comment: Required to pass other values in the form, here i had truncated the form

Comment: then what do you need? what it should be?

Comment: create a `ngModel` as you need to pass in your json. and set `(ngModel)` like that. at last pass `this.formData `. Ex. `this.formData = { "categoryMast": {
    "catCode": 12
  }, "ProductName":"Product A", "Price": 100.00 }`

Comment: Your model setup should like `(ngModel)="formData.categoryMast.catCode"` and `(ngModel)="formData.ProductName"` and `(ngModel)="formData.Price"`

Comment: formData is undefined..............searchIncident(formData:any){
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    // headers.set("Authorization", localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN));
   console.log("@@@@ :"+ formData);

Comment: you have to create `formData` object into `ISearchComponent`

Comment: Create a new model for formData. Defined that  formData:IncidentHeaderModel[]; . modified search <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="searchIncident(formData)">Search</button>. Still it returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps actually build the form like the model is built, so you end up with the form values exactly like you want. Depending on your model, this would be pretty intricate and could be hard to maintain if changes are made to the model. (The other viable option is to convert the values you get from the form to your model before sending it to the api, like suggested in comments).

And since you are using a form, you can scrap all the `ngModel`'s, that's what you can use your form controls for :)

So with your current setup, your form would be like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  categoryMast: this.fb.group({
    catCode: ['']
  })
});
```

And your html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<label>Category: </label>
<div formGroupName="categoryMast">
  <select formControlName="catCode">
    <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let category of categoryMaster" value="{{category.catCode}}">{{category.catDesc}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

This would give the object you are looking for:

```
{
  "categoryMast": {
    "catCode": ""
  }
}
```

### [**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPDHONH3YU8YJqbdknwW)